# Limiting Child Objects in Class Diagram

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram, generalization, multiplicity

I want to model a simple system using a Class Diagram:

- I have 3 possible classes: `Company`, `Employee`, `Manager`.
- The `Company` must have 20 `Employees` (aggregation?).
- The `Company` must have 1 `Manager` (aggregation?).
- A `Manager` is an Employee (generalization?).
- Each `Employee` can only be in 1 `Company`.

In other words, I want to limit this system to have 20 `Employees`, 1 of which must be a `Manager`. However ONLY 1 can be a `Manager`. This would make it so that there are 19 `Employees` and 1 `Manager` objects at all times.

I have the setup in my head of how I want this system to work, but I can't get the model quite right. This is what I got:

[image]

I feel like I am very close, but my issue is that although the `Company` 1 to 1 relationship to the `Manager` seems correct, the 1 to 19 to the `Employee` seems off. Since a `Manager` is an `Employee`, I have no way of limiting how many of those 19 `Employees` are `Managers`. I am trying to do this without splitting `Employees` up into `Non-Manager` and `Manager` classes.

Am I on the right track? Is there something I am missing? Or is it clear enough that 19 MUST be Employee objects and 1 MUST be Manager object?

Answer (score 3):

### The problem

Your model has a weakness: a `Manager` of one Company could be `Employee` of another, because nothing in your model says that the employment relationship with the `Company` is the same for both classes.

Why?  If you apply the UML generalization semantics:

- `Employee` has an association with `Company`,
- `Manager` is a specialization of `Employee`, and therefore inherits all its properties, operations and associations, including the association with `Company`.
- `Manager` has in addition its own association with the `Company`.  So it has two distinct associations: the inherited one and its own one.

### Potential solutions

It would be helpful to label the ends of the association, e.g.  `employer`/ `employee` and `company`/`manager`:

- The simplest solution could be to remove the association between `Manager` and `Company`, since it is inherited. But there is no easy way to tell that there must be a `Manager` among the `employees`.  Moreover, there wouldn't be an easy way to find the `Manager` of a `Company`.  So this solution does not appear appropriate.
- Another solution would be to add a constraint that specifies that for the `Manager`, `manager.company` is the same than `employee.employer`. Since a `Manager` manages one and only one `company`, no other manager could by deduction exist among the `employees`.  But this sounds somewhat artificial.
- The best solution in my view is therefore to keep both associations but use UML smeantics to explain that `company {subsets employer}` and `manager {subsets employee}` Be aware that this solution requires 20 employees, since it makes clear that the manager is one amont the 20.

If you're interested to know more about subsetting, I advise you [this artile about redefinition, specialization and subsetting of associations](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/9652/RedefinesSpecializationSubsettingExtendedVersion.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), which could also inspire you other variants.

### Minor remarks

The aggregation are fine.  However, aggregation is a [modelling placebo](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AggregationAndComposition.html) since the UML specs clearly say page 110:

> Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

Therefore, I'd suggest to avoid them  when possible.  You could therefore as well use normal UML associations.  Especially for the manager where there is only one.

Another remark made by [qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/qwerty-so) in the comments is that the `+` should be removed in `+has` : The `+` is about public visibility. It’s not the association itself that is public or private, but the [association end](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#association-end) (e.g. `employer` and `employee` in my proposal).

Comment: When I saw you edited the question I even didn't start writing an answer ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so  ok,  next time I answer fist and edit afterwards. Because I like to read your answers as well :-)

Comment: Well, your answers are usually so complete that I'm done with "there's a typo in yours".

Comment: Ah, one remark: the `+has` does not make sense. Looks like a mix between a name and a role. Should probably be mentioned.

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed a very relevant remark. I edited to give it more visibility.